# How can I get the uploaded file's filename in a way that TypeScript is ok with?

Tags: typescript, forms, filenames

I have a form where you can upload a file. I know two different ways to get the filename, but TypeScript doesn't like either of them. There are no errors in the compiled JS file, only in TS.

### HTML

```html
<form class="image-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="upload-file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload image">
</form>
```

### TS alternative 1

```
const form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('.image-upload')!
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const formattedFormData = new FormData(form)
  const data = formattedFormData.get('upload-file')!
  console.log('filename: ', data['name']); // error
})
```

#### Error

The error on data['name'] reads:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"name"' can't be used to index type 'FormDataEntryValue'. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'FormDataEntryValue'.ts(7053)`

To get this approach working, it seems to me that I need to assign data (type FormDataEntryValue) to a type that has the name property. I've googled around but I really can't find any information about which types there are that has this property.

### TS alternative 2

```
const form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('.image-upload')!
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('filename: ', document.forms['image-upload']['upload-file'].files[0].name) // error
})
```

#### Error

The error on 'image-upload' reads:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)`

I honestly don't know what I should do about this one.

### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the first alternative:**
If you are sure that it's only ever going to be a file, you can do type assertion like `as File`.

```
const form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('.image-upload')!
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const formattedFormData = new FormData(form)
    const data = formattedFormData.get('upload-file') as File
    console.log('filename: ', data['name']); // no error
})
```

You may also check `instanceof File` (see BorisTB's answer), if you don't mind it ending up within the JS code.

The method `get` is returning `FormDataEntryValue` (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get )
`FormDataEntryValue` is either `string` or `File`
(reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormDataEntryValue ) 
This means  you can use `typeof ... === "string"` or `instanceof File` checks to tell which type it is.

And from here you can see the properties of `File`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
(`name`, `type`, `lastModified` etc)

---

**For the second alternative:** 
I would avoid doing it in TS, because indexing `document.forms` with a `string` gives results with uncertain types (a `HTMLCollection` has properties like `'item'`, `'length'`, `'namedItem'`).
But you can technically do `document.forms['image-upload' as any]` (explicity `any`) just to silence the warning.

This approach has another issue: why do you get `document.forms['image-upload']` each time, when you know that it's always going to be the same `const form` defined just above it?
You could have done `form['upload-file'].files[0].name` (Somehow, TS doesn't complain about this even though `...['upload-file']` results in `any`. Maybe it's lenient once it detects a `HTMLFormElement`)

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if data really is a file. The easiest  way to do it is to use `instanceof`.

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const formattedFormData = new FormData(form)
  const data = formattedFormData.get('upload-file')!

  if (data instanceof File) {
    console.log('filename: ', data['name']);
  }
})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiATgWwFwwBIBUCyAZAMSWQFEAbAU2QrFgF4YATEYAV2toDoBHVixAJ4BlCpWBQkACgDknAJbIAhgHMKAWlYAHMiEWNpASgCEAKBMIUnPYxIA3GlDxzoNfjIisARsjlRpAGhhJCntaAxg6AD4YAG8TGBgQh05NRCTaABEKOEVWMihJA3iYUEhYCyUoKApGIhQMxShFCJgwCgB3GDrkBqbJCqKE0ugmRuaGCsbq2uJexU5VAuktHT01ODlKQ1NiuTggxjGYOTLFMGAKEH2CTYpwuISh8AgQSk4dZRkNyjBFanQAqMmgBtaS-ajSAC6BgA3MUAL4meEGIA)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `File` variable in which you would put `document.forms[0]['upload-file'].files[0]` :

This way, the interpreter would know that you are trying to access the `name` attribute of the class `File`, and that it has a `string` type and not `any`

Answer (score 0):

```
const form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('.image-upload')!
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log('filename: ', document.forms[0]['upload-file'].files[0].name) // error
})

if (form != null ) {
    const data = new FormData(form);
    for (const pair of data) {
        console.log(pair);
    }
    // OR
    for (const pair of data.entries()) {
        console.log(pair);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at line 5 of your *TS alternative 1*:

```js
const data = ... as File;
```